# Overloading method without modifying classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I have access to a class structure, which I cannot modify, as follows:

```
Graphics
  Circle
  Line
  etc.
```

Again, I cannot modify it! These all have individual properties such as `Radius`, `FirstPoint`, `LastPoint`, etc., as well as some common properties.

I want to create a method that accepts a `Graphics` object, and depending on the type of object, will run a `ToJson` method:

```
Graphics g = db.GetGraphic(123);
// Console.WriteLine(g.GetType()) prints "Circle"

// Should run some specific implementation for `Circle` type graphics, and
// have an overload for all types including Graphics
ToJson(g);
```

At first I imagined I could craftily overload the `ToJson` method:

```
ToJson(Graphics g) { ... }
ToJson(Circle g) { ... }
ToJson(Line g) { ... }
```

however this of course goes for the generic `ToJson(Graphics)` overload each time.

I'm sure I could do something like the following:

```
if (g is Circle) ...
if (g is Line) ...
if (g is Graphics) ...
```

or create a Dictionary to reduce the complexity for each type, but that doesn't feel like the best way of doing things

---

*What I've considered*

I've considered if there's some generic wrapper method I could use around each object (e.g., `new JsonGraphics(g).ToJson()`), but I do not want to have to perform any manual type checking myself.

I have looked at the double dispatch and visitor pattern, but I wasn't sure they met my requirements as they look like I have to modify these classes (or maybe I just didn't fully understand them), and (kinda obvious, however) generics are also basically out of the window as they require me to know in advance what type of `Graphics` object this is.

---

*Two questions then:*

Is there a better way to do this other than to use some Dictionary or something other `if (g is Type)`-like?

If I could modify the classes, how would the pattern look? This isn't possible in this case, but is double dispatch/visitor the best way to go in the case I could?

Comment: If you could modify the types, you would add a virtual/abstract ToJson instance method and override as needed. A "rule engine" where you use reflection to find the right implementation of the ToJson code is probably the best way to go.

Comment: So yes, a dictionary of type to delegate/object that implements this is probably what I would choose myself.

Comment: Decorator pattern?

Comment: Either double dispatch or visitor would serve the purpose, if it were not for the constraint that classes cannot be modified.

Comment: If he were to use a decorator pattern he would need to know which decorator to decorate each object with, and though he would have specific ToJson code for specific objects, he would still need some way of identifying which decorator goes to which object.

Comment: @KennethK. Please note the constraint that I **can't modify the base classes** - they're part of a dll!

Comment: @NickBull Yeah, that's the point of the decorator pattern.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Unfortunately I cannot as they're part of a dll that I cannot modify

Comment: Since I'm a rather big fan of dependency injection, personally I would probably create a generic interface with the ToJson method, and register one concrete implementation for each such type of graphics object, and resolve the right one at runtime.

Comment: I understood that you can't modify them, which is why I think a dictionary of type->delegate/handler object is probably your best option.

Comment: @KennethK. How so? I thought each class would need to inherit some interface in the decorator pattern

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Okay, that's unfortunate! :(

Comment: As you note, to use the visitor pattern for double dispatch, you need the "visited" class to implement a method that calls the "visitor" class back on the appropriate method. I give a simple example here: https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/04/wizards-and-warriors-part-three/  You normally use the visitor pattern when you have a group of related objects, you have a variety of analysis or transformation passes you need to perform on those objects, and the exact details of each operation depend on the run-time type of *both* the visited and visitor objects.

Comment: Thank you for your input Eric - I'll give that a read! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to modify the base class, or have access to the concrete type before it's turned into a generic `Graphics` type, unfortunately I don't think there's anything you can do except inspect the runtime type of the `Graphics` object.

You can use a switch statement (since C# 7.0), which is slightly cleaner than your `if` chain:

```
switch (g)
{
    case Circle circle: ... break;
    case Line line: ... break;
    default: /* Oh no! */ break;
}
```

Personally I don't see much advantage in using a Dictionary over a switch statement like this - both can be put away into a little self-contained method (and so reduce the *amount* of violation of the open/close principle), but the switch will be significantly cheaper.

You can also use `dynamic`, which causes the runtime to do late binding:

```
dynamic d = g;
ToJson(d); // Picks the right ToJson overload corresponding to the runtime type of 'd'
```

... although, dynamic has a fairly large runtime cost, and is generally considered smell.

Comment: The `switch` is using some pattern matching? I wasn't aware switch statements in C# could do that! :)

Comment: @Nick Yes, since C# 7.0

Comment: Oh man, it's been a while. I last used C# when it was at 5.0, I feel old

Comment: To be fair, nothing ground-breaking has happened since 5.0 (apart from Roslyn) - it's been lots of little improvements. C# 8 is going to be ground-breaking again, though